# Navigation drawer with camera permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

Hey I am trying to get permission when I wanted to launch application it consist of navigation drawer but when I open my application for first time it does not show permission popup even I had asked for permission in manifest.

Code 
**MainActivity.java**
Following class consist of implementation of navigation drawer and I had ask for checkSelfPermission in onCreate but nothing works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;

private View mLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }

    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA){
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //granted
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is `==`, it should be like below;

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```